# setting facility for syslogger in rails to something besides user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syslog

I am using the syslog-logger gem in ruby on rails.  This, by default, uses a facility called user, and a program called rails.  How can I set the facility to be something like 'local0' or 'local1' or any other facility?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require 'syslog_logger'
SyslogLogger::SYSLOG = Syslog.open('progname', Syslog::LOG_ODELAY, Syslog::LOG_LOCAL0)
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = SyslogLogger.new
```

Substitute the constant for the facility you want as the third argument to Syslog.open.  Note the LOG_ODELAY represents the default for the second arg; other values could be used there if you need special syslog behavior.

As to why this should work, take a look at the [initialize code](https://github.com/seattlerb/sysloglogger/blob/master/lib/syslog_logger.rb#L148) where you will see that Syslog is opened in the default way based on whether SyslogLogger::SYSLOG is set.